# Remove mixed extents in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

In SQL Server you can make sure that the engine uses the whole extent for a single object (i.e. a table). I know how to enable the trace `1118`, but that only applies to newly written data as I recall.

How can I make sure that `all the data` in the database is using uniform extents instead of mixed extents?

Can it be done by rebuilding the clustered indexes, and when not present creating and dropping a clustered index?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The actual problem I'm trying to resolve is that I want to make sure that the database doesn't use mixed extends anymore. If it does the required actions after I set the trace flag than I want to be sure that I don't have any mixed extends anymore.

Comment: Again, what si the **actual problem** you're trying to solve?

Comment: The thing I want to know if the mixed extents would be removed by and index rebuild after TF 1118. It turn out that it does.
It would potentially be a performance issue but using mixed and uniform pages together but it turns out there isn't a peformance issue unless it's in tempdb.

Comment: Remember that extents are not contiguous and extent fragmentation will affect only readaheads to a very less degree. If you have lot of heap tables, then creating a clustered index will help address extent fragmentation. As @RemusRusanu said, you need to revisit the problem you are trying to solve !  Read [this myth](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2930-fixing-heap-fragmentation/) and [stop worrying about fragmentation](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain answer is yes, if you have enabled trace flag 1118 on your instance a rebuild of those indexes will move them to full extends instead of mixed. You can get more information on this from Paul Randal's post: [Are mixed pages removed by an index rebuild?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/mixed-pages-removed-index-rebuild/)

A synopsis of the comment raised by `ray herring on July 10, 2014` and Paul's response:

Ray asked if enabling this flag, and performing rebuilds would move all the pages in mixed extends to dedicated extends. Paul stated yes it would. However one thing I would note is his second question, on if it was worth worrying about for existing tables and indexes. Paul stated, no, since mixed pages only really make a difference in performance is in tempdb.

So you are not likely going to see a great deal of performance increase by worrying about the current pages that are mixed. Just do your normal index maintenance and at some point they will get moved.

Comment: I just found the same post 30 seconds before your answer, lol. This makes sense and will make things easier for me when enabling the TF